# Powerapps checkbox in Gallery

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

I am creating a powerapp with a gallery, i added a checkbox withing the gallery and I also have a combobox in the gallery, I need to set default value in combobox when checkbox is checked. The combobox will only be visible when checkbox is checked, I added and index to the gallery to identify each gallery rows

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like that :

[image]

Please follow this steps :

1- your collection should be something like the following :

```
ClearCollect(
    colGallery,
    {
        Title: "A",
        YesNo: false,
        ComboList: ["1","2","3"]
    },
    {
        Title: "B",
        YesNo: true,
        ComboList: ["1","2","3"]
    }
)
```

2- insert your gallery and update the **Items** property with the your collection :

```
Items : colGallery
```

3- insert in your gallery a **label** for the title, a **checkbox** and a **combobox**

[image]

4- Update the **OnSelect** property of your gallery with the following formula :

```
Patch(colGallery,Gallery1.Selected,{Title:ThisItem.Title,YesNo:Checkbox1.Value,ComboList:ThisItem.ComboList})
```

5- on both **OnCheck** and **OnUnCheck** properties of your checkbox paste the following formula :

```
Select(parent)
```

6- on your combobox **OnVisible** property, use the following :

```
ThisItem.YesNo
```

This should help you.